# Prove that given a binary relation $\rho$ then $(\rho^n)^{-1}= (\rho^{-1})^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Prove that given a binary relation $\rho$ then $(\rho^n)^{-1}= (\rho^{-1})^n$

I have tried to take $\rho=(a, b)$ then $\rho^{-1} =(b, a)$ then $(\rho^{-1})^n = (b, a) \circ (b, a) \circ ... \circ (b, a)$ and I can say that $\rho ^n = (a, b) \circ ... \circ (a, b)$, but I don't think this is the right way to do it.

So, how do you do this proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Prove:** $P(n):=(\rho^n)^{-1}=(\rho^{-1})^n$

**Base Step:** $n=1\implies P(1):=\rho^{-1}=\rho^{-1}$. Hence $P(1)$ is true.

**Induction Hypothesis:** For some $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $P(k)$ is true, i.e., $(\rho^k)^{-1}=(\rho^{-1})^k$.

**Induction Step:** Now, $$(\rho^{k+1})^{-1}=(\rho^{k}\circ \rho)^{-1}= \rho^{-1}\circ (\rho^k)^{-1}=\rho^{-1}\circ(\rho^{-1})^k=(\rho^{-1})^{k+1}$$which shows that $P(k+1)$ is also true.

**Conclusion:** Therefore by the Principle of Mathematical Induction we conclude that $P(n)$ is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.